# Cannot connect client to Broker

Tags: lua, mqtt

I'm coding on lua for the first time and have created a mqtt client instance for a IO Link Sensor to publish data on a MQTT topic. However, I can't figure out how to connect to my local mosquitto broker, since "the connection is refused" but the broker is online and working.
The setup to my mqtt client looks like this:

```
local client = MQTTClient.create()
local BROKER_IP = '127.0.0.1'

local USE_TLS = false

client:setIPAddress(BROKER_IP)
if (USE_TLS) then
  client:setPort(1883)
  client:setTLSEnabled(true)
  client:setTLSVersion('TLS_V12')
  client:setCABundle('resources/mosquitto/mybroker-cert.pem')
  client:setClientCertificate(
    'resources/mosquitto/mqtt-client-cert-2.pem',
    'resources/mosquitto/mqtt-client-key-2.pem',
    'changemeclient'
  )
end
```

Now the error is marked on following client:publish line.

Remark: Here the data to be published is a distance and thus converted to string.

```
if dataValid == 'PI_STATUS_VALID' then
    local sDistance = string.format('%d', distance)
    client:publish('/topic/test', sDistance, "QOS0", "NO_RETAIN")
  end
```

Does anyone see were the problem could be?

Comment: What is the error? Just saying it's on that line isn't very helpful without knowing what it is.

Comment: `WARNING: AppEngine.Network.MQTTClient: App 'IOLink2MQTT': Pos 'IOLink2MQTTv2.lua:295'] publish error: The client is not currently connected.`

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65994820/edit) the question when adding details. When you add the error add more of the code where you setup and start the client. A link to the MQTT library you are using as well would be useful.

Comment: Also please add more information to your question. Is this Lua code running on the same machine as the broker? If not then `127.0.0.1` is the wrong IP address to use.